# TypeError: exports.[interface_name] is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I've created an Interface in Typescript NodeJS but I cannot wrap my head-around the error that says:

TypeError: exports.Something is not a constructor

```
interface Something {
    name: string;
    message: string;
    stack?: string;
}

interface SomethingConstructor {
    new(message?: string): Something;
    (message?: string): Something;
    readonly prototype: Something;
}

export declare var Something: SomethingConstructor;
```

This is what I have created as an Interface. And using it like so.

```
import { Something } from './dummy;

testFunction();

function testFunction() {
    try {
        const something = new Something("Here is a message");
        console.log(something.message)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('in catch block');
        console.log(e);
    }

}
```

I expected this would run and prints "Here is a message" in the console but throws the "is not a constructor" error. I might not know how I should use interfaces. Please shed light on how can I do something like it?

Comment: you haven't actually assigned a value to `Something` in your code, you've just given it a type. (I'm guessing that is a `.d.ts` file rather than an actual `ts` file.) So when you try to call it as a constructor, you get this error. If I'm making wrong assumptions (I could be), you need to show us more code.

Comment: I wanted to actually create custom exceptions for my backend and got inspiration from the ts Error interface which you're correct is in a `.d.ts` file. I am new to TypeScript and might not really know how can I go about it. Please guide how I should?

Comment: well the `.d.ts` just tells external code what your types are, but unlike actual Typescript it doesn't enforce those types actuall match the values (assuming they're written in JS). So the problem is as the error message says, your `Something` is not a constructor.

Comment: Yes. I need to know how to make it lol

Comment: that depends what you need that "class" to do. No-one can simply write that function for you without knowing its requirements.

Comment: I just simply need to create an object out of the interface I've written and make it work without providing me the [x] is not a constructor.

`const someObject = new Something("hello")`